# OSM to PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

I am trying to upload OSM files (PBF file) to my DB in PostgreSQL. I am using the osm2pgsql tool.

If I will upload one file (Ontario, Canada) and after a few days  another file (LA, USA) will it add it to the existing data or will it overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a manual for osm2pgsql at https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#running-osm2pgsql.

> **Working with Multiple Input Files**
>
> Usually you are using osm2pgsql with
> a single input file.
>
> Do not use osm2pgsql with more than one input file in versions before
> 1.4.0. It might work or it might not.
>
> Version >= 1.4.0 Osm2pgsql can read multiple input files at once,
> merging the data from the input files ignoring any duplicate data. For
> this to work the input files must all have their data from the same
> point in time. You can use this to import two or more geographical
> extracts into the same database. If the extracts are from different
> points in time and contain different versions of the same object, this
> will fail!
>
> Do not use multiple change files as input in append mode, merge and
> simplify them first.

So, it might work to import an older Ontario, Canada file and a newer LA, USA file if they are imported together because they may not contain any common objects. However, it is not possible to import Ontario first and LA a few days later into the same database. Import LA into a separate database. It is probably possible to merge the data in PostgreSQL later, see for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140021/postgresql-merging-identical-tables-from-separate-databases-into-single-database.

Comment: Thank you. You wrote " However, it is not possible to import Ontario first and LA a few days later into the same database". But I don't understand why?

Comment: Because osm2pgsql does not support that option. You can import one or more .pbf files at once. It is also possible to create a database that can be updated with a --slim option but even then the initial import is basically similar. Other tools like the GDAL OSM driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html can support your use case but does not create similar tables than osm2pgsql.

Comment: Thank you sir I appreciate your help